# ReactJs What is the difference between calling {this.functionName} and {this.functionName()}

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I have been using ReactJs for a couple of days now. And I find some syntax a bit curious. 
For example, sometimes I have to call a function this way:

```
{this.functionName}
```

Without the **parentheses** at the end.

And sometimes I have to call it like this:

```
{this.functionName()}
```

Like in this example:

```
  <button onClick={this.streamCamVideo}>Start streaming</button>
  <h1>{this.logErrors()}</h1>
```

See the difference between calling `this.streamCamVideo` and `this.logErrors()`.
Can someone please provide an explanation for this?

**EDIT 1:**
As requested, here are their definitions :

```
  streamCamVideo() {
    var constraints = { audio: true, video: { width: 1280, height: 720 } };
    navigator.mediaDevices
      .getUserMedia(constraints)
      .then(function(mediaStream) {
        var video = document.querySelector("video");

        video.srcObject = mediaStream;
        video.onloadedmetadata = function(e) {
          video.play();
        };
      })
      .catch(function(err) {
        console.log(err.name + ": " + err.message);
      }); // always check for errors at the end.
  }
 logErrors(){
      return(navigator.mediaDevices.toString())
  }
```

Comment: What are their definitions? But to answer your question, the first one isn't a function call. It passes a function reference to the `onClick` event handler.

Comment: For more simple `onClick={this.streamCamVideo}` execute on event call . For `{this.logErrors()}` execute on render.That means `()` is execute the function on immediately on render

Comment: @PatrickRoberts , I have added their definitions in the edit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`{this.streamCamVideo}` is a reference to the `streamCamVideo` function. You can think of `this.streamCamVideo` as a variable whose value is a function. Think about it like this:

```js
const myVariable = 'some text'

const myOtherVariable = function() {
  console.log("You are inside the myOtherVariable function");
}
```

Both `myVariable` and `myOtherVariable` are variables. One has the value of a string, the other has the value of a function. Let's say you want to pass both of these variables to another function:

```js
const anotherVariable = function(aStringVariable, aFunctionVariable) {
  console.log(aStringVariable, aFunctionVariable)
}

anotherVariable(myVariable, myOtherVariable)
```

You might see something like this logged to the console:

```
some text
[Function]
```

Notice that you don't ever see the text "You are inside the myOtherVariable function" logged to the console. That's because the `myOtherVariable` function is never called. It's just passed to the `anotherVariable` function. In order to call the function, you would need to do something like this:

```js
const anotherVariable = function(aStringVariable, aFunctionVariable) {
  aFunctionVariable()
  console.log(aStringVariable, aFunctionVariable)
}
```

Notice the parentheses after `aFunctionVariable()`? That's what it looks like to actually call a function. So in this case, you'd see something like this logged to the console:

```
You are inside the myOtherVariable function
some text
[Function]
```

The function is actually being called.

So in your example:

```js
<button onClick={this.streamCamVideo}>Start streaming</button>
<h1>{this.logErrors()}</h1>
```

`this.streamCamVideo` is just being passed as a variable to the `<button>` element. When the button is clicked, whatever has been assigned to `onClick` will be executed. That's when the function you passed as a variable will actually be called.

Also, notice the parentheses after `this.logErrors()`? The `logErrors` function is being executed. It is not being passed as a variable to anything.

Answer (score 2):

`{this.functionName}` means referencing the function on a particular trigger. this way function will get called only when triggered.

`{this.functionName()}` is an actual function call, this method can be used to pass arguments. this function call will get called when page renders. This way function will get called repeatedly without any triggers. To stop that repeated function call we can use callback. like the following,

`{() => this.functionName()}`. this way the function will get executed only once.

Comment: Okay, well-understood. But, why is one of them called without () and one with ()

Comment: @AhmedGhrib  `{this.functionName}` is a variable which refers to a function. so we can call directly as it is.. when we want to pass any args to the function we put `()` and pass. but when we call it like `{this.functionName()}`  it will be running repeatedly.. to stop we are using callback method. like I said in my answer. . @Cully have a great explanation on top.

Answer (score 1):

{this.functionName} is used a reference type and it does not create instance on every render but {this.functionName()} is creates an instance of functionName on every render

`<button onClick={this.streamCamVideo}>Start streaming</button>`

Here if you use this.streamCamVideo Now it uses the reference type it does not create an instance of streamCamVideo but instead of if you use like this

`<button onClick={()=>{this.streamCamVideo()}}>Start streaming</button>`

Now it creates an instance of streamCamVideo instead of using the reference of streamCamVideo. 
Creating an instance on every render it slows the performance of your application

Moreover, When evaluated, the first one is just a reference to the function, in the second case the function gets executed, and the expression will be evaluated to be the return value of the function.

Comment: I think this is the clearest and most correct answer, yet;

Comment: This is not correct. In neither case are you creating an "instance" of anything. Yes, in the first example you are referencing the `streamCamVideo` function. However, in the second example you're just creating a new function that calls `streamCamVideo` when executed. It does not create an "instance" of `streamCamVideo`. Also, your second example does not evaluate to the return value of the function because you wrapped the function body in braces. It would return the value of the function if it looked like `() => this.streamCamVideo()` or `() => { return streamCamVideo() }`.

Answer (score 1):

We can use **this.logErrors()** when you want the function to be invoked and its result returned immediately.
In React, we typically follow this approach to split parts of your JSX code to a separate function for readability or reusability.

For Example:

```
render() {
  someFunction() {
    return <p>Hello World</p>;
  }

return (
    <div>
      {this.logErrors()}
    </div>
  );
}
```

We can use **this.streamCamVideo** when you want only to pass the reference to that function to do something else.
In React, this is used while handling an event handler which can be passed down to another child-component via props, so that component can call the event handler when it needs to or when it gets triggered.

For Example:

```
class myExample extends React.Component {
  streamCamVideo() {
   console.log("button clicked!");
   }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Button someCustomFunction={this.streamCamVideo} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class Button extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <button onClick={this.props.someCustomFunction}>Click me</button>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Great explanation! Thank you :)

Comment: Glad to help :)

Answer (score 0):

```
...
this.functionName(args) {
...
}
```

When its called like

```
... onClick={this.functionName}
```

The react component accepts like

```
function SomeReactComponent({ onClick }) {
...
```

so that onClick function can be called like

```
...
onClick(someEvent);
...
```

so that your function can use those args

```
...
this.functionName(someEvent) {
...
}
```

When it calls like this

```
... onClick={this.functionName()}
```

onClick accepts the result of functionName, which should also be a function in this case.

Answer (score -1):

One is attribute, another with "()" is function.